# SilverLight File upload fails for file larger than 900kb (most of times)

Tags: c#, file, iis, silverlight, upload

I have quite old silverlight webapplication, whenever user tries to upload a pdf file larger than 900kb, it fails, with no error being logged in web service logs file

checked webconfig for httpruntime settings, maxRequestLength etc already high big MBs.

on uat, same settings works absolutely fine, but the issue only occurs on prod. uat is internal server but prod, have two web servers(windows 2008, iis 7), load balancers, firewalls, accessible from outside world. so I thought issue may b with network, so opened port 443 whitlisting my machine ip, tried upload file to both server directly by change in hosts file.

This did not work. so network guys said the issue is with application!
but then at odd times especially in mornings, I can upload file about 10MB fine, no issue whatsoever. tried different files of 3,4,5,6,7MBs etc and file upload fine on many occasions. but this does not work always. but do work fine occasionally on some mornings. on two occasions I tested and it worked fine from office pc in mornings and then from my home on Sundays mornings, it worked fine. but then later it stops again.

any help please?

Comment: Paragraphs go a long way to helping the people who want to help you

Comment: Sorry about that TheGeneral, just done some formatting now

Answer (score 0):

I m junk got the source of problem, the larger files were split into  chunks and uploaded to a staging folder,  once all chunks were to received a file  was created and  moved to destination folder on file server. It turned out, the file server was rejecting the continental requests/chunks, so I changed the staging directory on c drive on web server for testing and since it all worked perfectly. Have asked infrastructure team to find out why web service suspended by file server, it could be networking or antivirus software. Is this could be security issue on performing staging part on c drive on web servers?